# Why will std::function call destructor when an object was bound to a member function?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, bind

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class test {
public:
  test(){ p = new int[10];}
 void print_info(double a)
  {
    cerr << a << endl;
  }
  ~test(){
    cerr << __LINE__ << endl;
    delete []p;
  }
private:
  int *p;
};

int main()
{
    test t;
    std::function<void(void)> f = std::bind(&test::print_info, t, 2.0);
    //std::function<void(void)> f = std::bind(&test::print_info, std::cref(t), 2.0);
    return 0;
}
```

It will crash, since `test::~test()` is called twice. But, if I replace `t` with `std::cref(t)` (or `std::ref(t), &t`),  `~test()` will be called only once when exiting main().

I didn't figure out the reason. I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit, using gcc 4.6.3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're binding a copy of the object `t`. Since your class tries to manage dynamic memory, but doesn't follow the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722), it has invalid copy semantics - both copies will try to delete the same dynamic array on destruction.

If you used a class like `std::vector`, with valid copy semantics, to manage the dynamic array, then all would be fine.

Comment: Thanks very much for your valuable advice.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are binding a `copy of object t`, not `t` itself, that will be destructed when returning from `bind` object will be destructed and since you don't overload copy c-tor, default copy c-tor will make shallow copy and your `p` will be deleted twice. For binding `t` itself you should use `std::ref`.

Comment: +1 Which leads us to the problem that the implicitly defined copy-ctor here only makes a shallow copy. (Btw. its definition as defaulted is deprecated in C++11)

Answer (score 0):

```
std::function<void(void)> f = std::bind(&test::print_info, t, 2.0);
```

> It will crash, since test::~test() is called twice. But, if I replace t with std::cref(t) (or std::ref(t), &t), ~test() will be called only once when exiting main().

I didn't figure out the reason. I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit, using gcc 4.6.3.

The reason is actually quite simple, the `std::bind` function creates a functor object that holds a *copy* of the arguments. In your program there is a bug and copying objects of the type end up with two objects having pointers to the same memory and both calling `delete[]` in their destructors.

When you bind `&t` the *address* of the object (pointer) gets copied. There are no two separate objects, just one object and a pointer. Similarly the utilities `std::ref` and `std::cref` are *reference wrappers*, that is objects that wrap a different object and provide reference-like semantics. No matter how many times `std::ref` is copied, all of the copies behave as references to the same object. The object itself is never copied.

Comment: Yes, it's a bug. Thanks for your valuable advice!